# how to create a procedure to copy the data of one table to another table at specified time

Tags: sql, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

I want to create a plsql procedure which should get executed at 6 pm everyday and whole Data Of a day which is in a Temporary Table should Be Migrated to a base Table. After Successful Migration of Data it should Display a Count Of rows processed.

Comment: Vivek, have you already searched in the [PL/SQL docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm#LNPLS020)? Did you try anything? Please put some effort in solving your problem before asking...

Comment: Rightly said by @Armfoot You should also mention what you've tried so far.  For this requirement, you can also use insert into query and schedule it daily at required time.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not much clear, what i understood is you wanted some data operation to be performed at specific time. For that i would suggest you to use Scheduler JOB's with Oracle. For more Details for creating/scheduling/stopping job refer this -->  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/scheduse.htm#ADMIN12384